# Usage of Content Types, Site Collection Level List, Site Level List and List Template

Tags: content-type, custom-list

I have to create a list with some columns on several different sites. For that which process shall I use from the following and why :
Content Types, Site Collection Level List Site Level List and List Template?
What's the difference between all the four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just create list (not workflows and complicated relations), I think the best and easiest way is to create List Template. It's so easy to create, upload and to use on different sites. 
Hope it hepls.

Comment: Will this work if I am working on different site collection level?

Comment: Yes, it works for sites, subsites, subsites under subsites, etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

A flexible,practical and maintainable solution is to create a re-runnable `Powershell` script to deploy your `Site Columns` and `Content Types`and then you can create lists from these content types.

A good reference is here:
https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/bulk-creation-of-sharepoint-site-columns-and-content-types-with-powershell-part-1

You can also use CSOM (javascript or C#) instead of using `Powershell`